# Understanding spring boot long running behaviour

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, api, rest

I wanted to understand how the long running behaviour of Spring Boot works. Suppose we have a spring boot application with a few APIs written with `@RestController`. Now, when the application is run, we can call the API as many times as we want. Now, if the request rate is like 100 per second, how are those requests processed, is it like each request is handled separately by a thread or there is some other mechanism to handle multiple requests ?

To make it more clear, does it happen that 100 threads come alive for 100 requests per second or the process is somewhat different ?

Also a follow up question, when an exception comes up, the thread serving that request dies, and a new thread comes alive. But that doesn't affect other requests. So, how does that work, like if that thread was supposed to serve other upcoming requests, how are those requests going to be re-directed to other thread ?

Comment: Tomcat has a pool of threads (default 200) for serving requests. If you would take some time to read that documentation that would have answered your questions.